# Pulseaudio loopback makes pavucontrol malfunction

Tags: pulseaudio

I've plugged my old DVD player to my USB soundcard through its stereo analog input.

I can have the sound from the DVD player through the analog output of the soundcard, using module-loopback.

In the default.pa file, i add:
load-module module-loopback

This works and can be managed in pavucontrol only less than 30seconds until the sound is cut and i get a message in pavucontrol: "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait.."
No error message is displayed. Anybody knows why module-loopback stops working after being loaded?
Thanks in advance for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. Module-loopback had nothing to do with the matter. It just couldn't work properly with the sample rate parameters I've declared earlier in the `daemon.conf` file and crashed with this error displayed by the OS:

> pulseaudio crashed with sigfpe in pa_resampler_max_block_size()

Problem solved, then.